Looking for a woocommerce hook that fires when a product is created
I am looking in WooCommerce for a hook that fires when a product is created, to send an automatic email whenever a new product is created.
This is the function I am trying to call when a new product is created.
function new_product_created($product) {

    $product_id = $product->get_id(); 
    $date_created = $product->get_date_created(); 
    do_action( 'product_created',  $product, $product_id, $date_created); // Sends the info over to a different function to send an email about a new product being created.
}

When I try add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'new_product_created', 10, 2 ); the function never gets called.
This hook works; however, it seems to fire too early as it doesn't pull the product name or date created. add_action( 'save_post_product', 'action_save_product_data', 20);
This is the hook I am currently using that works to an extent. However, this also fires when the product is updated, which I don't want to happen.
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'new_product_created');


Note that save_post_product "pulls" the product name (or title) via $_POST['post_title'] and the date created via time().

The woocommerce_admin_process_product_object action is generated when a product is saved, which happens when a product is created or updated.
I think you are looking for the woocommerce_new_product action hook which is fired by the create function.

I've tried to use the woocommerce_new_product hook but my function never runs.  Not sure why that is.

Sorry, I missed the bit where you said you had tried that event. I saw a question about the new product event not firing on the Wordpress SE site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/315608/50368
Perhaps there's some information there to help you.
